# Copy file to a different directory

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am working on a project where I want to copy some files in one directory to a second already existing directory.

I can't find a way to simply copy from one folder to another. I can find copy file to a new file, or directory to a new directory.

The way I have my program set up right now is I copy the file and leave it in same directory, then move that copy to the directory that I want.

Edit:

Thanks everyone. All of your answers worked. I realized what I did wrong, when i set the destination path I didn't add a filename. Everything works now, Thanks for the super speedy responses.

Answer (score 72):

```
string fileToCopy = "c:\\myFolder\\myFile.txt";
string destinationDirectory = "c:\\myDestinationFolder\\";

File.Copy(fileToCopy, destinationDirectory + Path.GetFileName(fileToCopy));
```

Comment: I would rather use `Path.Combine` to concatenate path strings.

Answer (score 44):

```
File.Copy(@"someDirectory\someFile.txt", @"otherDirectory\someFile.txt");
```

works fine.

Answer (score 23):

[MSDN File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=VS.100).aspx)

```
var fileName = "sourceFile.txt";
var source = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileName);
var destination = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName);

File.Copy(source, destination);
```

Comment: In addition to answer [How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files and Folders (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx) and [Copy Multiple Files](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/55893-copy-multiple-files/)

Answer (score 8):

Maybe

```
File.Copy("c:\\myFolder\\myFile.txt", "c:\\NewFolder\\myFile.txt");
```

?

Comment: That doesn't copy a file *from one directory to another*, which is what's in the question.

Comment: @svick how's your answer different than mine?

Comment: It isn't now, but it was before you made your edit (look at the history of your answer).

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
    string picturesFile = @"D:\pictures";
    string destFile = @"C:\Temp\tempFolder\";

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(picturesFile);
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
       File.Copy(item, destFile + Path.GetFileName(item));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the destination directory doesn't exist, `File.Copy` will throw. This version solves that

```
public void Copy(
            string sourceFilePath,
            string destinationFilePath,
            string destinationFileName = null)
{
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceFilePath))
                throw new ArgumentException("sourceFilePath cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(sourceFilePath));
       
       if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destinationFilePath))
                throw new ArgumentException("destinationFilePath cannot be null or whitespace.", nameof(destinationFilePath));
       
       var targetDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(destinationFilePath);

       // this creates all the subdirectories, too
       if (!targetDirectoryInfo.Exists)
           targetDirectoryInfo.Create();

       var fileName = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destinationFileName)
           ? Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath)
           : destinationFileName;

       File.Copy(sourceFilePath, Path.Combine(destinationFilePath, fileName));
}
```

Tested on .NET Core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and it work for me

```
//I declare first my variables
string sourcePath = @"Z:\SourceLocation";
string targetPath = @"Z:\TargetLocation";

string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);

// To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
// Create a new target folder, if necessary.
if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
}

// To copy a file to another location and 
// overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

NET6 - Extension method

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public static FileInfo CopyToDir(this FileInfo srcFile, string destDir) =>
    (srcFile == null || !srcFile.Exists) ? throw new ArgumentException($"The specified source file [{srcFile.FullName}] does not exist", nameof(srcFile)) :
    (destDir == null || !Directory.Exists(destDir)) ? throw new ArgumentException($"The specified destination directory [{destDir}] does not exist", nameof(destDir)) :
    srcFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(destDir, srcFile.Name), true);
```