# How to copy images in one folder to another folder using c#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy a file to another path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979920/how-to-copy-a-file-to-another-path)

I need to copy images from one folder to another folder when my code starts to execute. Every time it starts to execute this should be happen.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979920/how-to-copy-a-file-to-another-path http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933/how-to-copy-a-file-in-c-sharp or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462997/copy-file-to-a-different-directory

Answer (score 4):

```
Public void CopyFiles(string sourcePath,string destinationPath)
{
     string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

     foreach(string file in files)
     {
        System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath,destinationPath);  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My take would be to use the following code -

```
public void CopyFiles(string sourcePath, string destinationPath)
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
        Parallel.ForEach(files, file =>
        {
            System.IO.File.Copy(file, System.IO.Path.Combine(destinationPath, System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file)));

        });
    }
```

Comment: PLINQ is awesome! (only in .NET 4 and above). It works by partitioning the source collection  and the work is scheduled on multiple threads based on the system environment. The more processors on the system, the faster the parallel method runs. BUT see Potential Pitfalls in Data and Task Parallelism [here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997392.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the file from one location to another by using [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx) method.